# Issue with running Winzip script in batch file through Informatica

Tags: batch-file

I am facing an issue while executing the winzip script through a batch file in Informatica.

I have prepared a batch script with below winzip command.
FOR %%f IN (%WorkingDirectory%*%FILE_VAR%*.txt)  DO "%StartDirec%\WINZIP32.EXE"  -a  %%~nf.zip  "%%f"

The problem which is occuring is when I run batch file for first time the Winzip prompts me to accept the Winzip usage, and once I accept all subsequent runs of batch file work fine when triggered manually.

But When the batch file is executed through Informatica it goes in an indefinite mode, the reason I could infer is the batch file is prompting the Informatica server user account to accept the Winzip usage which Informatica cannot handle itself.

I want to know is there any workaround for this, how can i bypass the prompt.

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Is using Winzip a necessity? Use the free and open source and far better 7-zip instead (7za.exe is the standalone command-line version).